# Как подключить css через подключенный js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Как подключить css через подключенный js?

Answer (score 9):

Создайте элемент `link` с нужными параметрами в заголовке страницы:

```
var tag_css = document.createElement('link');
tag_css.href = 'styles.css'; // здесь указывается URL стилевого файла
tag_css.rel = 'stylesheet';
tag_css.type = 'text/css';

var tag_head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
tag_head[0].appendChild(tag_css);
```

Comment: закинул этот код в js прописал путь, никакой реакции, что я делаю не так?

Comment: @l2banners Посмотрите сообщения об ошибках

Comment: @l2banners не пользуетесь средствами разработчика в браузере

Comment: @l2banners, вот вам пример, работающий: https://jsfiddle.net/xzhrh1cx/